# jQuery Anonymous Function Runs Twice via Event Delegation, Should Run Only Once

Tags: jquery

First time posting. Had some jquery issues, it took a while but I was able to work through it, now I just want to know why.

I have a CMS in which I'm trying to populate 2 form fields, one at a time, via a lightbox that's populated with images via an AJAX call. Click the browse images button next to the field, and an AJAX call is made to populate a lightbox with a series of images. Clicking an image closes the lightbox and populates the appropriate form field with that image's path.

The entire process works up until I go to make the 2nd image selection. Both form fields are populated with the second selection, thus erasing the first selection I made.

```
function AssetsPicker (el){
  this.el = el;
  this.url = el.attr('href') || '';
  this.gallery = el.data('gallery') || '';      

  this.show_assets = function(){
    //shows a lightbox of the thumbnails
    this.selected_asset();
  }

  //on thumbnail click
  //Grab the image src from the data attribute
  this.selected_asset = function(){
    var gallery = this.gallery, 
        empty_formfield = this.empty_formfield;

            //*************
            this was the problematic event. Works on first click, on second click it would populate both fields with the value.
           ********************//
        $('#lightbox_display').on('click', '.final-asset', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var   el = $(this);
          src = el.data('file');    

          empty_formfield(src, gallery);                
        });
    }

    //empty out the appropriate form field
    //populate appropriate form field with src  
    this.empty_formfield = function(src, field){        
      var targetfield = $('#edit_project').find("[data-field='" + field + "']");                
      targetfield.val('').val(src);     
      console.log("[data-field='" + field + "']");
    }

}//AssetsPicker

var AssetsAjax =  {
    images: function(url, gallery){
        var promise = $.Deferred();         
        $.ajax(url, {
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result){
                promise.resolve(result); //when we have a result, then resolve our promise
            },
            error: function(){
                promise.reject('something went wrong. sorry.'); //if an error, then reject our promise
            }

        });//$.ajax         
    return promise;
    }
}//var AssetsAjax


$('#edit_project').on('click', '.gallery-window', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this),
    url = el.attr('href');

  var assetspicker = new AssetsPicker(el);                  

  $.when(
    AssetsAjax.images(url)
  ).then(function(result){              
    assetspicker.open_gallery();
    assetspicker.show_assets(result);
  });       
});
```

Only when I changed this event handler did it work stop erasing the other field

```
    $('#lightbox_display .final-asset').on('click', function(e){
        //anonymous function unchanged              
    });
```

HTML

```
//lightbox that gets populated via AJAX depending on which browse <a> was clicked (thumbnails or large images)
<div id="lightbox_display">
    <a href="thumbs/3d-1.jpg" class="final-asset" data-file="3d-1.jpg"><img src="thumbs/3d-1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="thumbs/3d-2.jpg" class="final-asset" data-file="3d-2.jpg"><img src="thumbs/3d-2.jpg"></a>
    ...
</div>

//elsewhere in the DOM, both applicable fields
<div id="edit_project">
    <div>
        //clicked thumbnail image goes in here
        <input type="text" name="thumb" value="" data-field="thumbs">
        //this triggers the lightbox to show thumbnails
        <a href="file_assets/?q=thumbs" id="browse_thumbs" class="gallery-window" data-gallery="thumbs">Browse Thumbnails</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        //clicked large image goes here
        <input type="text" name="large" value="" data-field="large">
        //this triggers the lightbox to show large images
        <a href="file_assets/?q=large" id="browse_large" class="gallery-window" data-gallery="large">Browse Large Images</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Could it be you have nested `.final-asset` elements ? (*one `.final-asset` inside another `.final-asset` element*)

Comment: How and how many times are you calling the outer function ? (*the `function(field)` one*)

Comment: Is `<a>` and the inputs on the same DOM tree level? were is `#edit_project`? .find() looks for descendants and gives you more than one match if the there are more matches.

Comment: Are you sure the data-field attribute values are unique in your HTML?  While you mention you believe it's running twice, the fact that two "different" fields are having their values set implies that either you don't have unique data-field attributes, or as @GabyakaG.Petrioli suggests, it's something with how you're calling the function.

Comment: I am calling the outer function on click for two separate items(not shown in the code). I didn't post all that from the code because it didn't occur to me that the problem lied elsewhere. I will go back in and add the first click event that kicks off everything.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `$('#edit_project').on('click', '.gallery-window', function(e){` which is run on each click on the `#edit_project` element.

In there, after the ajax is complete, you run `assetspicker.show_assets` which in turn runs `$('#lightbox_display').on('click', '.final-asset', function(e){`

So each time your click on `#edit_project`, you ***add*** a new handler to the `#lightbox_display` for the `.final-asset` clicks.

Because i cannot understand what you are ultimately trying to do (*due to lack of complete html / live example*) i would suggest that you unbind the click handler each time (*so that only one remains active*)

So, alter the code inside the `assetspicker.show_assets` to

```
$('#lightbox_display')
    .off('click','.final-asset')  // added this line to ubind the existing handler
    .on('click', '.final-asset', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var   el = $(this);
        src = el.data('file');    

        empty_formfield(src, gallery);                
    });
```